# Is there a name for a function that returns only binary values?

Tags: functions, definition

Is there a name for a function that returns only binary values (e.g.,  $f(x) : X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$)?

Comment: It is a boolean function.

Comment: Absolutely it's a Boolean function, with $\textbf{B}= \{0,1\}$ baeing the Boolean domain.

Comment: Even your question is an example for a boolean function...